# Derivations of a semidirect product of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, semidirect-product

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ be two Lie algebras and let $\theta$ be a homomorphism of Lie algebras from $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{h})$.
We can then form the semidirect product $\mathfrak{g} \ltimes_\theta \mathfrak{h}$.
Its underlying vector space is the direct sum $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$, and its Lie bracket is
$$
  [(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)]
  =
  ( [x_1, x_2], \theta(x_1)(y_2) - \theta(x_2)(y_1) + [y_1, y_2] ) \,.
$$

> Can we describe the Lie algebra of derivations $\operatorname{Der}( \mathfrak{g} \ltimes_\theta \mathfrak{h} )$ is a sensible way?
> If so, can the necessary computations be done is a “clever” way?

---

As as special case of the above problem I have calculated $\operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h})$.
For this I’ve taken an arbitrary vector space endomorphism $\delta$ of $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$ and written it in matrix form
$$
  \delta
  \equiv
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \delta_{11} & \delta_{12} \\
    \delta_{21} & \delta_{22}
  \end{pmatrix} \,,
$$
so that
$$
  \delta( (x,y) )
  =
  ( \delta_{11}(x) + \delta_{12}(y), \delta_{21}(x) + \delta_{22}(y) ) \,.
$$
That $\delta$ is a dervation of $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$ can then be equivalently expressed by conditions on the matrix entries $\delta_{ij}$, which then gives a sensible description of $\operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h})$.
(One finds that $\delta_{11}$ and $\delta_{22}$ must be derivations, and that $\delta_{12}$ and $\delta_{21}$ need to be homomorphism of Lie algebras from one direct summand into the center of the other direct summand.)

I understand that I can apply the same approach for the semidirect product $\mathfrak{g} \ltimes_\theta \mathfrak{h}$, and that I will end up with *some* equivalent conditions on the matrix entries $\delta_{ij}$.
However, the calculations for the direct sum (i.e. the case $\theta = 0$) were already kinda annoying, so I’m hoping that there is a better way.
It is also not clear that the resoluting conditions on the entries $\delta_{ij}$ for $\operatorname{Der}(\mathfrak{g} \ltimes_\theta \mathfrak{h})$ will be something that I can interpret as something sensible.

Comment: There are some results, e.g., [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12215-019-00424-1), but in general there is no "sensible description", I think. Did you search for the corresponding question for groups (automorphism group of semidirect product)?